# WPF Xaml Rotation Animation Keeping Final State

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a rectangle and a button in a window and each time I click the button I would like to rotate the rectangle 60 degrees with an animation, my problem is that each time I click the button it reverts back to an angle of 0. How do I maintain the end state of the animation so as to go from 0 to 60 degrees on the first click, 60 to 120 on the second, etc...?

Here is what I have so far...
Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100"  x:Name="rect" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Fill="Red"/>  
    </Border>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Click="Button_Click">Rotate</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And code behind...

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation d2 = new DoubleAnimation(60, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
        RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();
        rect.RenderTransform = rt;
        d2.Completed += (s, eArgs) => rect.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(60);
        rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, d2);  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reuse a RotateTransform that is defined in XAML, like

```
<Rectangle RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ...>
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="transform"/>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

and run the animation by setting its `By` property:

```
transform.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation
    {
        By = 60d,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3)
    });
```